# Google Chrome 69, made my form Autocomplete Window, smaller and floating to the left

Tags: css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

Recently I updated my Chrome Setup, to Chrome 69. That resulted in all my forms, change their appearance and size a bit. That is fine, I don't mind. What needs to be fixed though, is the Autocomplete Window that appears when I type in a password or username.

I was wondering on how to fix that. Many more website and Web App, I visited Yesterday, don't have that problem.

For some reference, we use Bootstrap 3.3.7 for styling along with a bunch of overrides on it. We have an AngularJS application, with Redux for State Management. Probably all of that info won't help, but I included them anyway.

`Below` is a screenshot of the problem.
[Chrome 69 Autocomplete form bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5P0D.png)

Comment: Having the same problem, looks like the new version of Chrome auto-complete is more aggresive now

Comment: Yes, but whatever I do with the CSS, it doesn't seem to care. Also, if your viewport is smaller than medium, everything goes back to normal. This seems to be something that happens only on larger screens.